# manage.py help has different python path in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pythonpath, manage.py

I have a problem in virtualenv that a wrong python path is imported.

The reason is that by running the command:

`manage.py help --pythonpath=/home/robert/Vadain/vadain.webservice.curtainconfig/`

The result is right, but when I run `manage.py help` then I missing some imports.

I searched on the internet, but nothing is helped. The last change I have done is at the end of the file virtualenvs/{account}/bin/activate added the following text:

export PYTHONPATH=/home/robert/Vadain/vadain.webservice.curtainconfig

But this not solving the problem, somebody else's suggestion to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you simply tried `deactivate ` and then re-enable the virtualenv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved due to add a python path: add2virtualenv '/home/robert/Vadain/vadain.webservice.curtainconfig/'

Answer (score 1):

Don't see any problem there. You could also insert something like:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/robert/Vadain/vadain.webservice.curtainconfig/')
into your manage.py
```

Or you write a `setup.py` for your package and install it into your virtualenv (which would be the preferred way (`pip install -e`)